Is the data from Microsoft Clarity saved in a specific geographical location?
Is the Clarity data stored in a specific geographical region in Azure?
The Clarity documentation on Microsoft learn states that Clarity stores its data in the Azure cloud service, but there's no mention of the geographical location.
